# Distinct stylesheets for type, color and layout. What goes where?

Tags: css, typography

I came across [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/progressiveenhancementwithcss) on "A List Apart" that suggests spliting css information in (at least) three separate files, one for typography, one for layout and one for color information. Color seems pretty obvious, but how would you explain to your average programmer (that would be me) what's type and what's layout?

Answer (score 4):

typography is typefaces (fonts), their sizes, spacing, kerning, etc.

layout is the positioning, spacing, etc. of elements (div, span, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Type would be about the text itself.

Layout would be about the boxes (tables, divs and etc.)

Personally I would keep layout and text in the same file as one sometimes dictates the other and font information tends to be minimal (in my projects...).

Comment: we use one for layout+font sizing and a separate one for colours, this allows us to do white-labelling easily